# Как установить обработчик для index.php (главной страницы)

Tags: .htaccess

Есть код для `.htaccess` который обрабатывает все *url*, я его называю routing

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) /routing.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

То есть когда человек заходит на несуществующий файл: `site.ru/no_file` , я в routing.php ловлю строку (*no_file*) и выдаю посетителю нужный контент.

Хотелось бы чтобы и обращение к `site.ru` и `site.ru/index.php` и `site.ru/` так же передавалось на routing.php

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: А почему бы не назначить `DirectoryIndex routing.php` ?

Comment: @splash58 и тогда у всего сайта отлетят индексные файлы (index.php), которых там, скорее всего, не мало.

Comment: @de_frag при том, что написано в вопросе, это не очевидно. В корне у него вместо индекса routing почему-то, а есть ли какие-то папки - неочевидно

Answer (score 0):

Удалите `index.php` из корня сайта и измените свою конструкцию `mod_rewrite` на следующую:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule (.*) /routing.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```